# how to instantiate new file object javascript

Tags: javascript, blob

I'm having troubles instantiating a new file object in javascript.

Here's the general gist of what I'm trying to do. There is client side code that expecting a "file" type object. I need to access the file that's located on the server (game.smc), download it to the local machine and feed it to the client side code.

I did some research and found that creating a new blob object is the first step. But in the code below the blob object remains null and is never getting populated. Does the path in the xhr.open need to have the entire url? Maybe i'm missing an entire concept here not sure.

```
var blob = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xhr.open("GET", "/Roms/game.smc"); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() 
{
    blob = xhr.response;
}
xhr.send();
```

Once I can get the blob object populated I can then do this to convert it to a file object.

```
    function blobToFile(theBlob, fileName) {
        theBlob.lastModifiedDate = new Date();
        theBlob.name = fileName;
        return theBlob;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing. Shows how to get the blob object as well as convert it to a file type.

```
function autoLoadGame(fileName) {
    var gameLocation = '/Content/Roms/Snes/' + fileName;
    var blob = null;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", gameLocation, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            var blob = xhr.response;
            var file = new File([blob], fileName, { type: '', lastModified: Date.now() });
            snes_readfile(file);
        }
    }
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.send();
}
```